# Still not clear why longest path problem is NP-hard but shortest path is not?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete

I've heard/read many times that shortest path problem is P, but longest path problem is NP-hard. But I have a problem with this: we say longest path problem is NP-hard because of graphs with positive cycles. But if you think about graphs with one or more negative cycles, we don't have any polynomial time algorithm for the shortest simple path either. In fact, once can be reduced to another.

To summarize, we can find a shortest/longest simple path only if there are no negative/positive cycles. Also we can detect negative/positive cycles with Bellman-Ford in both cases. So under identical criteria, both problems should be considered NP-hard.

Comment: when we say that shortest path is in $P$, it is in non-negative graphs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm "for arbitrary directed graphs with unbounded non-negative weights"

Comment: That is Dijkstra's limitation. You can find a shortest path in graphs with negative weights (but not negative cycles) with Bellman-Ford, for instance. There's also another algorithm for DAGs with negative weights.

Comment: yes, I meant graphs without non-negative cycles (since in that case, adding $|\min w|$ to all the weights transforms the graph with negative weights into an equivalent non-negative graph suitable for Dijkstra). so you have no question anymore ?

Comment: @user1952009: Adding a constant to all edge weights does not lead to an equivalent problem, because it does not add a constant to all *path* lengths. (Otherwise there would be no need for the Bellman-Ford algorithm.)

Comment: @Rahul yes you are right, sorry. do you see anything else to say ?

Comment: I do still have a question. It's written up there :) We are using inconsistent definitions, so we can't say one is P versus the other is NP-hard - they're apples and oranges. As in, it's not a sensible comparison.

Comment: so you continue ? the shortest-path problem is for non-negative graphs. when there are negative cycles, it becomes the longest-path problem. it is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The longest path problem is commonly understood as follows: given a graph, find the longest *simple* path. Simple means that no vertex is visited more than once. Only in graphs with cycles can a vertex be visited more than once. The shortest path problem, however, is commonly defined for *simple* paths in *acyclic* graphs.

The difficulty for finding simple paths in graphs (possibly containing cycles) is easy to prove from the [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), i.e., a path visiting all the vertices.
The reduction is easy, just assign length 1 to all edges. A Hamiltonian path exists iff the longest path has length n-1.

Comment: hesitant to upvote since not clear, a picture would help